# Does $x\longmapsto Ax$ invertible where $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I had an exam this morning and a question was:

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and consider $$f:\mathbb R^2\longrightarrow  \text{Span}\big((1,0,0),(0,1,0)\big)$$

defined by $f(x)=Ax$. Does $f$ is invertible ?

I answered yes since the column are linearly independent (and thus $f$ is injective), and it's range is $\text{Span}((1,0,0),(0,1,0))$. Therefore it's bijective and thus invertible, no ?

But the answer was no and I don't understand.

Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Note that the way you wrote $A$, it's supposed to work on column vectors with 2 entries. Do you just identify $(a,b,c)$ with $\begin{pmatrix}a \\b\\c \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a &b&c \end{pmatrix}^T$?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct with the injectivity.

If we view $f$ as a map to $span\{(1,0,0)^T,(0,1,0)^T\}$, then $f$ is indeed surjective, and hence bijective. If we consider $f$ mapping to $\mathbb R^3$, then it is not surjective anymore (as e.g. $(0,0,1)^T\notin ran A$).

But as stated in the question, we can even write down the inverse:

$$f^{-1}((a,b,0)^T)=\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: But $(0,0,1) \notin Span\big((1,0,0),(0,1,0)\big)$

Comment: @addy2012: Yes, I realized this after I posted it. See my amended answer.

Comment: So I'm true and it's bijective, right ? But what could be it's inverse ? is it $A^T$ right ? Can I conclude it's symetric ? (since AA^T=I$)

Comment: Yes, it's bijective. The inverse is, as I wrote in my answer, indeed given by $A^T$. The matrix $A$ is by no means symmetric, as $A\neq A^T$ (even the number of columns and rows don't match). Note that we have $A^TA=I_2$ (the 2x2 identity matrix), but $AA^T$ is not the identity matrix in $\mathbb R^3$, but the identity mapping in $span\{\dots\}$.